# How can courier-imap and courier-pop accept both username and username@domain?

Tags: courier, courier-imap

I have `courier-imap` and `courier-pop` installed on a server, and they authenticate with username and password. The user database is LDAP, although, as far as I can see, courier doesn't know that; apparently it uses PAM, and PAM is in turn configured to use LDAP.

I want courier to accept `username@domain` as an alias for `username`, but I cannot find how to do it.

(The reason I want it is that the whole service will move to another service which serves many domains, and thus needs the `@domain` suffix; there will be a transition period when the old server will still be serving the emails, but during which users will be asked to modify their settings from `username` to `username@domain`, so the system must be able to work with both.)